# How to scrape javascript dynamic website

Tags: python, selenium, request, scrapy

i've been trying to scrape the website below but having some problems.I cannot find how they build the list of empresas(in english : companies) that they show. 
    When i select some categorie and submit the form, the url doesnt change, i've tryed to look in the request but no sucess.(not a webdeveloper here ).

```
    http://www.vitrinedoexportador.gov.br
```

I first tried to go though all links in the webpage. The first approach that i've tried was bruteforcing all the urls. They has this syntax.
"http://www.vitrinedoexportador.gov.br/bens/ve/br/detalhes/index/cdEmpresa/" + 6 digit code + "#inicio".

But i think that trying out 999999 possibilities would be wrong way to aproach the problem. 
The next approach that i'm trying is navigatin through the pages using selenium webdriver.
with the code below:

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('http://www.vitrinedoexportador.gov.br/bens/ve/br#a')
    # navigate to the page
    select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('cdSetor'))
    print (select.options)
    for opt in select.options:
        print (opt.text)
        opt.click()
        if(opt.text != 'Escolha'):
            opt.submit()
            time.sleep(5) # tem q colocar esse  para a página poder carregar.
            listaEmpresas = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("h6")

            for link in listaEmpresas:
                print(link)
            print (listaEmpresas)

            listaEmpresas[0].click()
```

But seens incredibly slow, and i only could get still one companie, is there a more smart way to do this?

Other approach that i've tried is using scrap, i can already parse a entire companie page with all the fields that i want. so if u guys help me in the way to get all the IDS , i can parse in my already built-in scrapy project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something very similar to this already and there is no super easy way. There is usually no list with all companies, because that belongs to the backend. You have to use the frontend to navigate to a page where you can build a loop to scrap what you want.

For example: I clicked the main url, then I changed the filter 'Valor da empresa' which has only five options. I chose the first, which gave me 3436 companies. Now it dependes if you want to scrap details of company or only main info, like tel cep address that are already in this page. If you want details you have to build a loop that clicks in each link, scrap from main page, go back to search and click on the next link. If you need only main information, you can already get that on search page by grabbing `class=resultitem` with beautifull soup, and looping through data to get first page. 
In any case, next step (after all links of first page are scraped) is pressing the second page and doing it again.

After you scrap all 3436 of first filter, do it again for other 4 filters, and you would get all companies

You can use other filters, but they have many options and to go through all companies you would have to go through all of them, which is more work.

Hope that helps!

Comment: i'm doing this way you've said. is there any suggestion to make selenium run fast ?